# Create more objects of the same type

Tags: xtext

I have a DSL with some constant and variable declarations, like:

```
const c1 : Int
const c2 : Int

vars
  v1 : Int
  v2 : Int
  b : Bool
```

But I would like to have something like this:

```
const c1, c2 : Int

vars 
  v1, v2 : Int
  b : Bool
```

I couldn't find a way from the grammar to have that...What would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this my do a model 2 model transformation using IDerivedStateComputer
see http://xtextcasts.org/episodes/18-model-optimization for an example